# How to initialize a Singleton then initialize ViewModels In SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, swiftui, initialization, singleton, viewmodel

How to initialize view models after a singleton in swiftUI? I have an app in swiftUI. There are two views: ClassPosts View, where users can see posts made in their class at university, and a use profile view, where users can see their profile and posts they have made. These are both within a tab view. In the tab view I initialize the view models as state objects, and pass them into both views as environment objects. I know it is standard practice to have one view per view model, but that is not the basis of my question.I have a singleton, UserMananger, that holds the user information as a userDocument. In the UserManager, on the init, I make a call to firebase to get the user document, and set the properties of the userDocument to the returned values. After this returns, I need to be able to initialize the view models based on the UserManager Singleton. Getting posts for the user depends on the information in the singleton.

I tried making the userDocument property in the UserManger singleton @Published, but this did not fix the problem because the call to get the documents from firebase only happens once, while the user document has not yet returned. More broadly, I do not know if there is a better way to structure this. I asked ChatGpt4 if I could have a userDocument property in each of the view models, used the Auth.auth().currentUser? in the view models to get the email address, and make a call to get the user document in each view model, but it gave reasons why that is a bad idea, because it could lead to inconsistencies. Below is my current code. Note: The view router is what I use to go between views on the onboarding, it isn't relevant here, and is not causing the issue.

The TabView:

```
struct InAppView: View {
    @StateObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    @StateObject  var userProfile: UserProfileViewModel = UserProfileViewModel()
    @StateObject var posts: ClassPostsViewModel = ClassPostsViewModel()
    let userManger: UserManager = UserManager()
    let customAccentColor = Color(red: 75 / 255, green: 175 / 255, blue: 210 / 255)
    var body: some View {
        TabView() {
            ClassPosts(viewRouter: viewRouter)
                .environmentObject(userProfile)
                .environmentObject(posts)
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
                        Text("Posts")
                    }
                }
                .tag(1)
            UserProfileView(viewRouter: viewRouter)
                .environmentObject(userProfile)
                .environmentObject(posts)
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                        Text("Profile")
                    }
                }
                .tag(0)
        }
        .accentColor(customAccentColor)
        .onAppear {
            let uiColor = UIColor(red: 75 / 255, green: 175 / 255, blue: 210 / 255, alpha: 1.0)
            UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
            UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()
            UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
            UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.systemGray3
            UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = uiColor
        }
    }
}
```

The UserManager Singleton:

```
class UserManager: ObservableObject {
    
    static var shared: UserManager? = nil
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    @Published var currentUser: UserDocument?
    let firebaseManager = FirestoreService()

    init() {
        self.getDocument(user:self.getCurrentUserEmail()){ doc in
            self.currentUser = doc
        }
    }
                         
                         
    private func getCurrentUserEmail() -> String {
        let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
        return currentUser?.email ?? ""
    }

    func getDocument(user: String, completion: @escaping (UserDocument?) -> Void) {
            guard !user.isEmpty else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            let doc = db.collection("Users").document(user)
            
            doc.getDocument { documentSnapshot, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error fetching document: \(error)")
                    completion(nil)
                    return
                }
                
                guard let data = documentSnapshot?.data(),
                    let firstName = data["FirstName"] as? String,
                    let lastName = data["LastName"] as? String,
                    let college = data["College"] as? String,
                    let birthday = data["Birthday"] as? String,
                    let major = data["Major"] as? String,
                    let classes = data["Classes"] as? [String],
                    let email = data["Email"] as? String,
                    let profilePictureURL = data["profile_picture"] as? String
                else {
                    print("Invalid document data or missing fields")
                    completion(nil)
                    return
                }
                
                let retrievedDoc = UserDocument(FirstName: firstName, LastName: lastName, College: college, Birthday: birthday, Major: major, Classes: classes, Email: email, profilePictureURL: profilePictureURL)
                completion(retrievedDoc)
            }
        }
}
```

The important parts of the ClassPost view Model related to initalization:

```
class ClassPostsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var postsArray: [ClassPost] = []
    @Published var repliesArray: [Reply] = []
    @Published var curError: String = ""
    
    @Published var isLoading: Bool = false
    @Published var selectedClass: String = ""
    let firebaseManager = FirestoreService()
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
  
    init() {
        self.getPosts()
    }
    
    
    func getPosts() {
        guard !self.selectedClass.isEmpty, let college = UserManager.shared?.currentUser?.College else {
            print("Error: Class or college is undefined")
            return
        }
        
        firebaseManager.fetchPosts(fromClass: self.selectedClass, fromCollege: college) { [weak self] (posts, error) in
            if let error = error {
                self?.curError = "Something went wrong getting the posts for \(self?.selectedClass ?? "this class")"
                return
            }
            
            self?.postsArray = posts ?? []
        }
    }
    
}
```

The relevant parts of the UserProfileViewModel:

```
class UserProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var usersPosts: [ClassPost] = []
    @Published var curError:String = ""
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let firebaseManager = FirestoreService()
    
    
    func getPostsForUser() {
        guard let college = UserManager.shared?.currentUser?.College else {
            return
        }
        
        firebaseManager.getPostsForUser(college: college) { [weak self] posts, error in
            guard let self = self else {
                return
            }
            
            if let error = error {
                // Handle the error
                self.curError = "Something went wrong getting your posts. Try Again."
            } else {
                self.usersPosts = posts ?? []
                // Perform any additional operations with the updated userPosts
               
            }
        }
    }

    init() {
        self.getPostsForUser()
       }
}
```

My main goal is trying to initialize the UserManger before I initialize the view models. I only want one instance of the UserManager. Thinking about this now, would I be able to initialize the Usermanger with a completion handler inside the .onAppear of the tabview, and then initialize the view models within the closure? Any help on code or program structure would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is a pretty long question, please try to turn it in to a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so it's more useful to others and easier to answer.

Comment: This is as simple as I can make it while providing all the relevant information.

Comment: you custom colors, tab bar customization, etc. isn't relevant to the question. Furthermore, a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) means translating your issue into a general issue that more users can relate to and find rather than trying to simplify your specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the new `.task` modifier you can use firebase via async/await and then you don't even need those Combine observable objects and it will simplify the code.

Make your firebase controller a custom `EnvironmentKey`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I need a reference to the current user, currently via a user manager class. Can you elaborate on what objects I would not need? I am assuming you are talking about the view models.

Comment: Yes remove all the view model objects and use the view model structs

Answer (score 0):

Answer: I ended up just combining the two view models into one view model, and then shared it across the views as an @environmentObject. This has worked so far.
I think this is better designed. Everything is synced with each other this way.